# HTML float right drop to next line

Tags: html, css-float

I am having difficulty to layout this right. two div side be side sitting in a container div like this

```
<div style="width:800px; height:50px; border:solid 1px black;">
    <div id="LeftBox" style=" border:solid 2px red; width:500px; float:left " >Left box</div>
    <div id="RightBox" style=" border:solid 2px green;width:400px; float:right;" >green box</div>
</div>
```

If the left box is small enough, it shows two box side by side. If the left box is too long then
the right box will drop a line which I don't want that behavior. I would like to set the right box 
to where it is no matter how long is the left box. Please help!!!!!

Comment: What do you want to do with the left box when the `size of the left box + size of right box` exceed the size of the container?

Comment: That is working exactly as it should. You could do an absolute position, right:0 and make the container relative. Other than that you don't have much options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning, then the elements don't affect each other:

```css
#Box {
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#LeftBox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 500px;
}

#RightBox {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Box">
    <div id="LeftBox">Left box</div>
    <div id="RightBox">green box</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think what I did wrong was that I did not set the container box to position:relative.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try, as [css-tricks recommends](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/float/), to set the container that the `float: right` is now bleeding into, to `clear: both`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Left Box to drop instead of the Right Box, just change the order of your divs:

**DROP LEFT INSTEAD:**

```
<div style="width:800px; height:50px; border:solid 1px black;">
    <div id="RightBox" style=" border:solid 2px green;width:400px; float:right;" >green box</div>
    <div id="LeftBox" style=" border:solid 2px red; width:500px; float:left " >Left box</div>
</div>
```

One of these divs will need to drop below the other if you are setting the width of the container div to less than the combined width of the nested divs.